# Help customising admin bar, removing buddypress links from dropdown

Tags: customization, buddypress, admin-bar

I am trying to customise my admin bar.  I have achieved most of what I need to do but am stuck on a couple of things.

1. I want to remove most of the links from the dropdown menu that appears when you moveover, "How are you, Name?".  I want to keep the top part with the profile link and image but want to remove all the links below that.  ie.  Activity, Profile, Notifications, Messages.
2. I want to use a font icon for the Home link but this doesn't appear, random characters appear instead.  Does anyone know why?  My code is below:

```
//add home page link in top left adminbar - want to use font icon but its not working.
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'add_toolbar_items', 100); 

function add_toolbar_items($admin_bar){     
    $admin_bar->add_menu( array(         
        'id'    => 'home',         
        'title' => '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>',         
        'href'  => '/',         
        'meta'  => array(             
            'title' => __('Home'),                     
            ),     
        ));     

 } 
//trying to remove Activity, Profile, Notifications, Messages etc links but doesn't do anythingW
remove_action( 'bp_adminbar_menus', 'bp_adminbar_blogs_menu', 6 );
remove_action( 'bp_adminbar_menus', 'bp_adminbar_notifications_menu', 8 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove items from the toolbar you could try using [`$wp_admin_bar->remove_node`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_node) like so:

You'll have to use an inspect element to find out the IDs but if you would want to remove the WordPress logo you could inspect it and see:

`<li id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo" class="menupop"> … </li>`

Then you would target the ID like so:

```
function remove_wp_logo( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'wp-logo' );
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_wp_logo', 999 );
```

---

I'm not sure if [Font-Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) is installed with BBPress ( I know it's not in WordPress ) so you'll need to make sure you [admin-enqueue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) the fonts first. Otherwise, you'll have to work with [Dashicons](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#welcome-widgets-menus) ( which is installed into WordPress )

Comment: Thank you I have used Css to remove the part of the menu Idontwant.  I have already installed fontawsome and its working fine throughout the site apart from on the admin bar.

Comment: @LeeTee - Installed font-awesome **how**? It's working fine throughout the **Admin Panel**? If it's through a plugin it may only be installed on the front-end of your website only. You should be able to View Source ( CTRL + U ) and see the font-awesome css linked somewhere, is it in the header or footer?

Comment: Ive used wp_enqueue_style to add the stylesheet to the front end.  I want to add the homepage icon to the admin bar on the front end.  I assume from what your saying I need to install it to the admin panel as well.  Thanks for your help.